# How to run a specific file using python

Tags: python, function

I'm kinda new to Python and I need help.
So basically I want to make a function that will run a specific file (.vbs, or some app). How do I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling an external command from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-from-python)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the first question. Please watch out grammar and check if your question isn't already answered on SO. Almost all common questions are already answered :)

Comment: Here is the [`subprocess` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it:

```
import os
os.system("C:/path/to/your/file.exe")
```

Another:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["python", "C:/path/to/your/file.exe"])
```